# Can my Flutter project have a different version number for Android and iOS?

Tags: flutter, dart

Is it possible to use pubspec and the flutter build tools to create release versions of my app with a different version for each platform? Eg iOS could be 1.0.1+10 and Android 5.2.3?

This is wrong but I'm thinking something like like the below

```
name: myapp
description: my app description
ios_version: 1.0.1+10
android_version: 5.2.3
```

Currently the apps in the stores have different version numbers. Would we need to bump them both to the same version, say 6.0.0? Is it possible to have a pubspec for each version?

Answer (score 2):

For iOS find the file name **Generated.xcconfig** and change the following parameter

> FLUTTER_BUILD_NAME=1.0.0
>
> FLUTTER_BUILD_NUMBER=1

Otherwise, default version getting from **pubspec.yaml** from the following line :

> version: 1.0.0+1   // default version set

Answer (score 1):

For Andriod edit the local.properties file inside android folder when you are building.

For iOS edit the Generated.xcconfig file inside ios/FLutter folder or update from Xcode when you are building.

```
FLUTTER_BUILD_NAME=1.0.0

FLUTTER_BUILD_NUMBER=1
```